# Sort part of an array by value

Tags: php, sorting

I have a pretty simple array:

```
array(
    1 => 'asdf.php',
    2 => 'jkl.php',
    3 => 'qwer.php',
    4 => 'ty.php',
    5 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_a',
    6 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_g',
    7 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_i',
    8 => 'zxcv.php',
    9 => 'oiu.php',
    10 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_w',
    11 => 'bnm.php',
    12 => 'hgb.php',
    13 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_p'
)
```

My goals is try to retain the same order of the array except I want all the items with the string "?param=my_val" to be next to each other, also retaining their order. So the end result would be:

```
array(
    1 => 'asdf.php',
    2 => 'jkl.php',
    3 => 'qwer.php',
    4 => 'ty.php',
    5 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_a',
    6 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_g',
    7 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_i',
    8 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_w',
    9 => 'edit.php?param=my_val_p'
    10 => 'zxcv.php',
    11 => 'oiu.php',
    12 => 'bnm.php',
    13 => 'hgb.php',
)
```

I've been playing around with usort() and I've been able to get them all together, but keeping the same basic order has got me struggling. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Where do all of the `param` entries need to go? At the beginning/end of the array? Are you wanting to maintain the sorting of the `param` entries within themselves? I'm not clear on exactly what you mean by "Keeping the same basic order"

Comment: does the first param=my_val determine the start of all the other ones?

Comment: Yes to all. See my gist here: https://gist.github.com/solepixel/5289626 - Let me know if you have a better way, but for now, this is working.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (assuming you have your stuff in `$arr`):

```
$parts_with_param = array();
$parts_with_no_param = array();
foreach ($arr as $val) {
  if (strpos($val, '?param=my_val') !== false) {
    $parts_with_param[] = $val;
  } else {
    $parts_with_no_param[] = $val;
  }
}

// merge into a new variable or overwrite $arr if you like
$new_arr = array_merge($parts_with_param, $parts_with_no_param);
```

Comment: This was close, actually, but it lost the original order. It did however help me to come to this conclusion, which seems to work:
https://gist.github.com/solepixel/5289626